# Delete elements from nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list with the following structure

```
list={ {x,y},{ {a1,b1},{a2,b3} } }
```

where the number of pairs `{ai,bi}` can be different. I would like to remove pairs `{x,y}` with `y<0` and try to use

```
DeleteCases[list,{{_,b_},{__List}}/;b<0]
```

but this returns all elements of the list. What do I wrong?

**Update**: I have understood why my attempt is wrong but still do not understand how to remove these elements.

Comment: For the `DeleteCases` approach, I recommend using the level argument. e.g. `DeleteCases[list, {_, b_} /; b < 0, Infinity]`

Comment: but you can't do `b<0` on symbol.

Comment: Are you removing the entire entry in the list if conditions are satisfied or just the {x,y} pair?

Comment: Artem, your initial `DeleteCases` method does work, perhaps your list structure used for this is not like how I define `lst` in my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a modification of the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/223663/63039) to do this.

```
lst = {{{x1, -1}, {{a1, 1}, {c1, d1}}}, 
   {{x2, 1 }, {{a2, -1}, {c2, d2}}}, 
   {{x3, -1}, {{a3, 1}, {c3, d3}}},
   {{x4, 1}, {{a4, -1}, {c4, d4}}}};

Extract[List@*First/@Position[a_/;a>=0][First/@lst]][lst]
```

> ```
> {{{x2,1},{{a2,-1},{c2,d2}}},{{x4,1},{{a4,-1},{c4,d4}}}}
> ```

Or

```
Cases[{{x_,y_},{a__List}}:>{{x,y},{a}}/;y>=0][lst]
```

> Same output.

If you need to only remove the `{x,y}` pair, I would need to think about that.

**Edit:** I thought about it:

```
lst/.{{a_,b_?Negative},{c__List}}:>{{c}}
```

> ```
> {{{{a1,1},{c1,d1}}},{{x2,1},{{a2,-1},{c2,d2}}},{{{a3,1},{c3,d3}}},{{x4,1},{{a4,-1},{c4,d4}}}}
> ```

This way loses the ordering, but it works with `Cases` and shows a terrible way to pseudo-use multiple conditions:

```
Cases[{{x_,y_},{a__List}}:>Evaluate@#]&/@{Unevaluated[{{x,y},{a}}/;y>=0],Unevaluated[{{a}}/;y<0]}//#[lst]&/@#&
```

> ```
> {{{{x2,1},{{a2,-1},{c2,d2}}},{{x4,1},{{a4,-1},{c4,d4}}}},{{{{a1,1},{c1,d1}}},{{{a3,1},{c3,d3}}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
list/.{_,_?Negative}:>Nothing
```

Comment: I think this will remove pairs of {a,b} that satisfy the condition also.

Comment: This way works if you use `{{_,_?NegativeQ},{__List}}`.

Comment: The biggest problem for this answer to be valid is, that this question has `Cases[list, _?NumberQ]` is empty `{}`! So it can not be jugded by Mathematica this way meaningful. This correctly recognized by @CATrevillian! Otherwise this asked for an example from the Mathematica documentation: [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html] section Scope example 1: replace negative numbers with `0` or something or `Nothing`. From [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html] section Properties and Relation are other concepts available.